# Pattern: how subtract matched character in character class?

Tags: java, regex

Is it possible to subtract a matched character in a character class?

[Java docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html) are having examples about character classes with subtraction:

```
[a-z&&[^bc]]    - a through z, except for b and c: [ad-z] (subtraction)
[a-z&&[^m-p]]   - a through z, and not m through p: [a-lq-z](subtraction)
```

I want to write pattern, which matches two pairs of word characters, when pairs are not the same:

```
1) "aaaa123" - should NOT match
2) "aabb123" - should match "aabb" part
3) "aa--123" - should NOT match
```

I am close to success with following pattern:

```
([\w])\1([\w])\2
```

but of course it does not work in case 1, so I need to subtract the match of first group. But when I try to do this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\w])\\1([\\w&&[^\\1]])\\2");
```

I am getting an exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Illegal/unsupported escape sequence near index 17
([\w])\1([\w&&[^\1]])\2
                 ^
    at java.util.regex.Pattern.error(Pattern.java:1713)
```

So seems it does not work with groups, but just with listing specific characters. Following pattern compiles with no problems:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\w])\\1([\\w&&[^a]])\\2");
```

Is there any other way to write such pattern?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("((\\w)\\2(?!\\2))((\\w)\\4)");
```

Your characters will be in groups `1` and `3`.

This works by using a negative lookahead, to make sure the character following the second character in the first character group is a different character.

Answer (score 1):

You are using the wrong tool for the job. By all means use a regex to detect pairs of character pairs, but you can just use `!=` to test whether the characters within the pairs are the same. Seriously, there is no reason to do *everything* in a regular expression - it makes for unreadable, non-portable code and brings you no benefit other than "looking cool".

Comment: @Kilian: this pattern is just one of many (there are also plenty simple ones) for matching string parts - so this is not just for being "cool" as you say - system iterates through patterns and matches them... If I would go with your suggested way - I would have it even more "uncool" solution as I would need to add custom `ifs` for one or another case...

Comment: @flesk: very nice, +1 from me! :)

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
String regex = "(\\w)\\1(?!\\1)(\\w)\\2";
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
```

`(?!\\1)` is a [negative lookahead](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html), it ensures that the content of `\\1` is not following

My test code

```
String s1 = "aaaa123";
String s2 = "aabb123";
String s3 = "aa--123";
String s4 = "123ccdd";

String[] s = { s1, s2, s3, s4 };
String regex = "(\\w)\\1(?!\\1)(\\w)\\2";

for(String a : s) {
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(regex);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(a);

    if (matcher.find())
        System.out.println(a + " ==> Success");
    else
        System.out.println(a + " ==> Failure");
}
```

The output

> aaaa123 ==> Failure
>   aabb123 ==> Success
>   aa--123 ==> Failure
>   123ccdd ==> Success